# React JS: How to use UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate correctly?

Tags: reactjs

Some warning messages appear on the browser console when I use UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate or so on. The warnings say that "UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate is not recommend". So I would like to know how can I prevent to render components in the right way. I suppose UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate is only for the development stage.

Comment: Read this [article](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/whats-new-in-react-169) (the second link in google request)

Comment: Then, UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate will be in the deprecated methods' list so it's recommendable avoid it and use getDerivedStateFromProps instead of, right?

Comment: There's `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle function. Perhaps you can extend `PureComponent`? If you provide a more concrete example of react usage in your code then we may be able to provide a more specific answer other than to not use deprecated functions.